# VS 2013 Update 3 - Not TypeScript support

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I've installed VS 2013 with update 3 which I believe should give me TypeScript support.

Unfortunately although I have the TypeScript templates I don't have any basic features like intellisense or highlighting, when I went to investigate I found I had not TypeScript option under Tools > Options > Text Editor.

I've tried reinstalling but to no avail and given the TypeScript indicates VS 2013 update 3 has full support I'm not sure how best to proceed?

Comment: It was first released in Update 2.  Did you skip that update?

Comment: I did simply because I only installed in the  last few days v3 seemed to indicate it was cumulative (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43721) so I assumed it would include previous ones. I'm not sure v2 update is actually available for download anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a `TypScript` project to your solution via `Open` / `New Project`  and then double click `TypeScript` in the installed list on the left and then select the type of `TypeScript` project you want to create and then use the Wizard from there.

Comment: Yup I have the templates but when I use them and open a TS file in the resulting projects I don't get the basics like intellisense.

Comment: Very peculiar intellisense does work for TypeScript here and I am using VS2013 Update 3 as well.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what's gone wrong, it doesn't have TypeScript listed all in Tools > Options > Text Editor so its not surprising it isn't working but I've tried completely deinstalling and reinstalling and nothing changed.

Comment: Ah yes, and on mine the Tools/Options/Text Editor does show it (and the options). I did see that others have had this problem http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1768 . I also saw elsewhere that someone had some kind of extension added to VS that conflicted with VS and Typescript specifically. Wonder what would happen if you remove any installed extensions and see if the problem rectifies itself.

Comment: Thanks yeah, I'd been trying VS Ultimate edition, switched back to Professional and it now works fine.